# Can the sum of a element from a subspace and another element not in the subspace be in the original subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $U \subset V$ be a finite-dimensional subspace of $V, dim(U) < dim(V)$. Take $u \in U$ and $v \in V$ \ $U$, is it always the case that $u + v \in V$\ $  U$?

I think yes, since $U$ is closed and if $u + v \in U$, that would mean that $v \in U$, contradicting the hypothesis.

Asking just in case I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: A small comment. There's a distinction between forward slash / and backward slash \. The notation $V\backslash U$ denotes the set $V$ with $U$ removed. The notation $V/U$ on the other hand denotes the quotient space of $V$ by $U$. I assume you mean the former, even though you write the latter. Otherwise, your reasoning is correct. If $u\in U$ and $v \in V\backslash U$ then we must have $u+v \in V\backslash U$. Otherwise $v = (u+v)-u$ is in $U$ by closure.

Comment: Yes, it's the former, my bad. Thank you.